# How to build relationships while onboarding remotely with a traditionally non-remote team?

Tags: new-job, relationships, telecommute, covid-19

I am starting a new position at a company that is normally co-located in the same office. However, due to Covid-19 the team has moved to a remote set-up and I will be joining the team remotely for a significant period of time until things return to normal.

What strategies can I use to establish and build relationships with my fellow teammates before we all eventually get back into the office? I am concerned that while the current team has been able to utilize their current 'social capital' they've built over months/years of working closely with each other in person, I am starting from scratch and need to build the relationships remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share hobbies and other fun facts in a variety of ways. Start meetings with 5 minutes of small-talk it creates a habit of encouraging some informal conversation and primes people for the discussion as well. Remember key dates and do something about it like The date the employee was hired and The birthday of the employee.

Comment: I'd be careful with small talk at official meetings. I'm always annoyed when my boss asks how it goes first while I'm already mentally prepared for important work topics (plus it's wasting my time). At least be receptive to how well that is taken and make sure to not delay meetings. If you want to do that I'd suggest to arrive earlier and do smalltalk until everyone is there only.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout your chat tool if you have one: Often there are additional "#fun" or "#spam" channels that are meant for off-topic conversation. If there is none, maybe at some point suggest one - unless everyone is doing small talk in one of the main channels anyway.

If you have something to discuss/clarify that takes more than one or two sentences, ask colleagues for one on one voice chats. You can always slip in some casual conversation there, e.g. while you look something up.